# Why does beyond compare opens git diff in merge mode?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

We have made the transition to git in my project and now I want beyond compare to work as it should with it. I have read the instructions on the [scootersoftware page](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows). I have tried both alternatives, just now I am using the old one with this in my .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = "\"c:/program files/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
```

That doesn't work as i expect it to. This opens up the beyond compare tool as it should, but for some reason I get into the merge mode with three windows at the top and one at the bottom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am getting the windows that you're hoping for, here are my settings.

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3x
    renames = copies
[difftool "bc3x"]
    cmd = \"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

I have had this same set up for years and hasn't caused me any problems. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether your case is the same as mine, but I had a similar issue, but it was caused by the merge settings which were also in the .gitconfig

My settings contained lines like

```
[merge]
tool = BeyondCompare3

[diff]
guitool = BeyondCompare3

[difftool "BeyondCompare3"]
path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe
cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"

[mergetool "BeyondCompare3"]
path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe
cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

What appears to happen is that git uses the latter option (with four parameters) rather than the former.

The workaround was to rename the mergetool from

```
[mergetool "BeyondCompare3"]
```

to

```
[mergetool "MergeBeyondCompare3"]
```

which means that it uses the difftool version with two parameters.

You would expect that you should also be able to change the first section to

```
[merge]
tool = MergeBeyondCompare3
```

but if you do that then the command `git difftool file1.txt file2.txt` uses Merge rather than diff which takes use back to where we were.

Downside is if you actually want to use merge, you will need to use the `-t MergeBeyondCompare3` command line option.